# Plotting ccxt graph in python

Tags: python, ccxt

I want to plot a live graph in python using matplotlib and ccxt can anyone guide me through it?

I have already plotted a live bitcoin graph but i am not able to plot all the graphs by one single commands of using the ccxt library.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question immediately, but launching [this example of basic charting with ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/py/basic-chart.py) should give you something like this:
[image]

From there is should be trivial to do the same with matplotlib. Hope it helps.